# Trying to get random quote and share intent via sms, whatsapp, bluetooth

Tags: android, facebook, textview

So, I developed an activity that shows random quotes from a external file (quotes.txt) in a single TextView. It works fine. Now, what I'm trying to do is to get this random quote displayed on screen and share via sms, bluetooth, facebook, whatsapp, and so on...

I implemented the share Intent. But it doesn't work. In fact, there is something wrong. I'm a newbie. Here's my code below

MainActivity.java

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Quotes.add(line));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));




    return true;
}



}
```

Menu Main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

Comment: what is happening, with above code, any exception, does share activity even start, if you select what happen next, what are you not getting

Comment: How to solve this? :/ I'm a newbie. I want to get the text from Textview (random quote) and share this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, ""); //<=adding blank quotes
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Quotes.add(line));    
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
```

**EDIT:**

You need to define your `TextView` on class level in `Main` **Activity**

```
TextView textView ;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //defining view at class level, make it accessible in all method
        //initalize the view in onCreate() instead of updateTextView()
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.widget_textview1);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, ""); //<=adding blank quotes
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textView.getText().toString());    
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
}
```

In your `updateTextView()` method, do this

```
private void updateTextView() {
    List<String> Quotes = getListFromTxtFile("quotes.txt");
    int nextInt = random.nextInt(Quotes.size());
    textView.setText(Quotes.get(nextInt));    
}
```

Accept the answer, if it helps!!

Comment: So, this ("line)" is red marked (it doesn't work): shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Quotes.add(line));

Comment: ok, my bad, what do you want to do, share the quotes from option menu or context menu(long click on any view eg `TextView`), is that what you are trying to do?? doing what you want to share quotes?

Comment: I want to share the quote line (R.id.widget_textview1) displayed on screen read from quotes.txt to eg. bluetooth or sms. Option Menu

Comment: Ok..it works now!! But if I update the textview... the share intent doesn't update (it gets the first quote displayed when I started the Activity).

Comment: @EckerBottini share the screenshot image for your activity also, if the text is updating, it should get the new quote, see code `textView.getText().toString()`, still share so that i can take a look, upload here and share the url=> http://imagebin.org/?page=add

Comment: @Ecker it is simple, just removed the line `public void buttonClick(View view) {
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.widget_textview1); 

    Random random = new Random();
    List<String> Quotes = getListFromTxtFile("quotes.txt");
    int nextInt = random.nextInt(Quotes.size());


    textView.setText(Quotes.get(nextInt));

}` from `button click` method and you are good to go

Comment: Remove the line `TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.widget_textview1);` from button click method